# selectmenu drop moves on resize

Tags: jquery-ui, position

I'm using jquery-ui selectmenu and have noticed if you leave the drop menu open and resize your window, the drop menu moves independently of the select.

Here's a fiddle with a totally stock usage:

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/65q0fL5r/

The odd thing is that the example on the jqueryui site doesn't have this issue, even though it's the same code.

Is there an easy fix for this?

```
$(function() {
  $( "#select" ).selectmenu();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my quickfix: On window resize, close and re-open the selectmenu if it is currently open:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.js-selectmenu').each(function() {
        var open = $(this).next().attr('aria-expanded') == 'true';

        if (open) {
            $(this).selectmenu("close");
            $(this).selectmenu("open");
        }
    });
});
```